Let, $A\in M_{3\times3}[\mathbb{C}].$ If for some integer $k\geq1$, all the eigenvalues of $A$ are $k^{th}$ root of unity, then $A^k=I$ is it true?
Let eigenvalues of $A$ are $\cos\frac{2l\pi}{k}+i\sin\frac{2l\pi}{k}$, where $l=0,1,\cdots,k-1.$ Now, \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\det(A) & =\prod\limits_{l=0}^{k-1}(\cos\frac{2l\pi}{k}+i\sin\frac{2l\pi}{k})\\
        & =\cos[\frac{2\pi}{k}(0+1+2+\cdots+(k-1))]+i\sin[\frac{2\pi}{k}(0+1+2+\cdots+(k-1))]\\
        & =\cos(k-1)\pi+i\sin(k-1)\pi\\
        & =(-1)^{k-1}\\
\therefore \det(A^k) &= [(-1)^{k-1}]^k=(-1)^{k(k-1)}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
For $k$ being odd or even $k(k-1)$ is always even. So, $\det(A^k)=1.$
From here how to proceed!!

What if$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\0&1\end{pmatrix}?$$

Here eigenvalues are $1,1$. By given condition, the eigenvalues for $2\times2$ matrix should be $1,-1$

Why? In my example, all eigenvalues are $1^{\textrm{th}}$ roots of unity, right?

No, for $2\times2$ it should be $2^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity, which are $1,-1$

@RITAMSADHUKHAN $1$ is a "2th" root of unity, so every eigenvalue of $A$ is a 2th root of unity.

@RITAMSADHUKHAN Also, the question never says that $k$ is the same as the size of the matrix. In the question, $A$ is $3 \times 3$ but $k$ can be any positive integer.

ok, now its clear

I missed that it should be a $3\times3$ matrix. Anyway, take$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\0&1&1\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$and $k=1$.
